# How to specify space around vertical rules in tabular

Tags: tables

This information probably exists in many places but unfortunately I couldn't find it.

In a table's format (using `tabular` and the `array` package) I can specify `@{\kern5pt}` if I wish to modify space added between cells.

But how can I do this by maintaining the vertical rule?

Is there some way to insert the equivalent of the vertical rule `|` inside `@{…}` so that I do get a vertical rule between the two cells, and such that it works just like `|`? (arbitrary height fitting the cell's height).

When I write

```
\begin{tabular}{c@{\kern3pt$|$\kern3pt}c|c}\hline
$\displaystyle\int f(x)dx$ blabla & blabla & blabla\\
$\displaystyle\int f(x)dx$ blabla & blabla & blabla\\\hline
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

I do get vertical rules between the 1st and the 2nd column, but they are small rules, not flexible ones like between the second and the third column, which fill the whole height of the table.

Is there some command that I can insert inside the `@{…}` so that I get the same result between column 1 and column 2, as between column 2 and column 3?

Comment: `\vline`  instead of  `|` ? Why you should do this? Defining common `\tabcolsep` is not an option?

Comment: Great Zarko, that's the command I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no need to do it *inside* the `@{}` as you can add more than one declaration between tabular columns:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\kern3pt}|@{\kern3pt}c|c}\hline
$\displaystyle\int f(x)dx$ blabla & blabla & blabla\\
$\displaystyle\int f(x)dx$ blabla & blabla & blabla\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I haven't thought of that (always thought that `@{}` is replacing space between cells, not that it could be combined with `|`), thanks!

Comment: @yannis, you can upvote answer too :-)

Answer (score 2):

Reduce `\tabcolsep` on one side of column is simple to achieve by use of the `tabularray` package. Using it you will have benefit with spacing nodes' contents too:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}
\usepackage{tabularray}   % <--- new
\UseTblrLibrary{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{tblr}{colspec = {Q[r,$$]| c | c},
             column{1} = {rightsep+=-3pt},
             column{2} = {leftsep+ =-3pt},
             }
    \hline
\int f(x)dx \text{ blabla} & blabla & blabla\\
\int f(x)dx \text{ blabla} & blabla & blabla\\
    \hline
\end{tblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

However, you can change your code fragment to:

```
\documentclass[border=3.141592]{standalone}

\begin{document}
\begin{tabular}{c@{\kern3pt \vline \kern3pt}c|c}\hline
$\displaystyle\int f(x)dx$ blabla & blabla & blabla\\
$\displaystyle\int f(x)dx$ blabla & blabla & blabla\\\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

and get

[image]

Answer (score 2):

For [`tabularray`](https://ctan.org/pkg/tabularray) package, there is a secret optional argument for column type `<` and `>` to set `rightsep` and `leftsep`, respectively.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tabularray}

\begin{document}

\begin{tblr}{c <[3pt]{} | >[3pt]{} c | c}
\hline
  $\displaystyle\int f(x)dx$ blabla & blabla & blabla \\
  $\displaystyle\int f(x)dx$ blabla & blabla & blabla \\
\hline
\end{tblr}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I hate secrets , however thank you very much for info. +1, but please add this secrets in package documentation for version 2022A.

Comment: maybe not in next version, but definitely I will add it some day.